# Check if SWF is being loaded by being embedded to an HTML page or not (direct accessed)?

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I want an idea to check if my SWF is being loaded from my HTML page by embedding or if it's being directly accessed.

I've tried many things but they are being kinda ruined with caching issues.

Thanks.

Comment: There are quite a few ways to accomplish this.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis I tried `ExternalInterface`, it worked but cache messed it up by loading the SWF on an HTML page then directly accessing it, it still detected that the `ExternalInterface` was my HTML page.

Comment: What JS were you calling from `ExternalInterface`?  Or were you checking `ExternalInterface.objectID`?

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis `document.location.href.toString`

Comment: I find it odd that a cache would interfere with that.  Then again, I haven't used Flash in a web browser in over 5 years.    Can you try seeing what `objectID` outputs in both scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

Pass in some data from the html page then access it using loaderInfo.parameters.

Couple this with loaderInfo.url to validate if its inside a html page but outside the server.